# jQuery flickers my navigation twice in desktop view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created an online resume using Bootstrap3 and for the top navigation i use a scrollspy. The navigation is enclosed in a collapsible drop down menu for mobile which does not work with scrollspy. The problem was that if i clicked a menu item in the mobile view, the page would scroll to the correct section but the menu would remain open.

To fix this i added a javascript at the end of my document which now closes the navigation after i click a menu item.

This however caused a problem in the desktop version of my site:
If i click a menu item the entire menu will flicker on the first two clicks. After the second click any menu item works without the flickering.

How could i get rid of this issue?

Here is the link to my site:
http://goo.gl/yjV8mq